# Using predict in survival analysis with quantile

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am working on survival analysis and fit a model using

```
srFit <- survreg(formula = Surv(time) ~ f1 + f2 + f3 + f4 + f5 + f6 + f7 + f8 + f9 + f10, data = train, dist = dist_pred[i_dist])
```

Then I use predict to predict lifetime of test users using

```
pred <- predict(srFit, newdata=test, type='quantile', p=c(90 / 100))
```

I want to predict the time when probability of surviving is less than 0.9, but I'm not sure whether using quantile is the right way. In general I don't understand what does quantile mean here, does it mean probability of surviving is less than 0.9 or probability of death is less than 0.9.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the examples from `survival::predict.survreg`? They seem, to me, sufficient to answer your question... But to be clear--no `type= 'quantile'` does not predict the time until `P(T>t) < 0.9`

Comment: I have looked at ?predict.survreg and  http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/survival/predict.survreg.  But I don't understand it and not sufficient. Could you please help me to understand??

Comment: I meant `example(predict.survreg)`, not the help file. But, it sounds like you may not have a solid background in either statistics or survival analysis (or perhaps both). What is your technical background?

Comment: My background is out of context. I just want a good document about predict with quantile.